# Windows Server 2008 Failover Cluster - Licenses

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, failover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

If I have a two node Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Failover cluster that needs to support 200 users, do I need to purchase 400 Client Access Licenses (200 for each node in the cluster), or do I only need to purchase 200 total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll delete this if I'm wrong (I'm not a licensing expert), but in my experiences Per User licenses are just that - per user. If you have 200 users, you'll need 200 licenses.

Comment: @Farseeker you are dead on.  CALs are per named user or per named device and are not tied to the server at all.